# A puzzle from 'The origin of the hidden supersymmetry'

Tags: supersymmetry

In the paper [arXiv:1004.5489](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5489) The origin of the hidden supersymmetry, the author use {Qa,Qa}={Qb,Qb}=2H, {Qa,Qb}=0 for N=2 hidden SUSY, which is different from what I was taught: {Qa,Qa}={Qb,Qb}=0, {Qa,Qb}=2H. I think they are controversially different. Is any of them wrong? If not, could anyone help by explaining some more?

Comment: The indices don't match for $\{Q_a,Q_b\} = 2H.$ What happens if you put $a=b$, for example? On the RHS, you should have some object that carries the right indices (such as $\delta_{ab}$, if $a,b$ live in some Euclidean space).

Comment: Yes that was confusing. Now I fixed the notation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could anybody give a hand on this? Isn't it supposed not to be a hard question...?

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. $a$ and $b$ are NOT fixed labels, i.e. you should *never* write down $\{Q_a,Q_a\} = \ldots$ or something like that. If you're really confused, you *can* write $\{Q_1,Q_1\} = \ldots,$ $\{Q_1,Q_2\} = 0$ etc. They are truly indices that can transform; you could rotate the supercharges, or write down $T_{\pm} = Q_1 \pm Q_2$, for example. The authors' $\{Q_a,Q_b\} = 2\delta_{ab} H$ is definitely right (up to a possible choice of conventions, of course).

Comment: It's actually the same as with normal QM commutators you learned years ago. At the beginning, you write $[x,p_x] = \ldots$ etc., but at some point you grow up and just put $[x_i,p_j] = i\hbar \delta_{ij}$. The latter is manifestly $SO(3)$ invariant (if $i = 1,2,3$).

Comment: I think I got it. In the paper what they describe by the anti-commutation relation is the relation between two diffenrent susy's and how they are related to our QM hamiltonian. Is that correct?